Unable to trigger Livewire model value update inside Laravel component
I have a Laravel component for a date range picker. The problem is that when I select the date range, the Livewire model cannot seem to register it, and it does not update the model value. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I have another component like this for a date picker somewhere else, and it works just fine.
Laravel daterange component:
@props([
    'error' => null,
    'disabled' => false,
    'val' => null,
    'mode' => 'range',
])
<div class="inline-flex rounded-md relative"
     x-data="{ value: @entangle($attributes->wire('model')) }"
     x-on:change="value = $event.target.value"
     x-init="flatpickr($refs.input, { mode: '{{ $mode }}', dateFormat: 'Y-m-d', minDate: 'today', defaultDate: '{{ $val }}' })">
    <input {{ $attributes->whereDoesntStartWith('wire:model') }} x-ref="input"
           @disabled($disabled) id="daternage-picker"
           x-bind:value="value" type="text" placeholder="Select Date Range"
           class="block w-56 py-2 px-4 text-sm border border-gray-300 rounded-lg focus:bg-gray-50 text-[#7C8DB0] placeholder:text-[#7C8DB0] placeholder:text-base placeholder:leading-6 @if($error) focus:ring-danger-500 focus:border-danger-500 border-danger-500 text-danger-500 pr-10 @endif disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-gray-200"/>
    <div class="absolute inset-y-0 end-0 flex items-center pe-4 pointer-events-none">
        <svg class="ms-2 -me-0.5 h-4 w-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none"
             viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                  d="M19.5 8.25l-7.5 7.5-7.5-7.5"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>

component call:
<x-daterange-picker wire:model="date" mode="range" :error="$errors->first('date')" :val="$date"/>

My livewire component:
class Table extends Component
{
  public $date = '';

  public function updatedDate()
  {
      dd($this->date);
  }

  public function render()
  {
      return view('livewire.admin.table');
  }
}


Could be because thedate property on your model isn't mass-assignable. Make sure to include date in the model's $fillable array.

@kylepg There is no model involved, the date property is just the variable in Livewire component that I am trying to populate using the daterange-picker component

Got it. Could you update your question to include the rest of the relevant component code?

@kylepg Edited, if you can help me out.......

Drop passing the $error, it's part of the service container and accessible anywhere. Apply the livewire model inside the x-daterange-picker. Try <x-daterange-picker mode="range"/> and use wire:model='date' inside the component. You don't need to pass the $date value either. It's a blade component right? Not a <livewire:your-component>?

@DimitriMostrey tried your solution but not working.

I found the mistake. When calling the daterange-picker component, we have to use wire:model.live property instead of simple wire:model
